# Every ring $R$ with $K ⊆ R ⊆ L$ (subrings) is a field $\Leftrightarrow$ $L/K$ is algebraic

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification, field-theory, extension-field, algebraic-groups

I have this exercise where I am having some problems solving it:

Show that for a field extension $L/K$ the following are equivalent:

(a) $L/K$ is algebraic.

(b) Every ring $R$ with $K ⊆ R ⊆ L$ (subrings) is a field.

For $a \Rightarrow b$

Let $L/K$ be algebraic and let R be a subring of L with $K ⊆ R ⊆ L$.
We take a $x \in R\backslash \{ 0 \}$. $x$ is algebraic over $K$. This implies that there exists a polynomial $f \in K[X]$ with $f(x)=a_n x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0=0$

So we have that $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0+1=1$ and therefore $x(x^{n-1}+a_{n-1}x^{n-2}+...+a_1+\frac{a_0+1}{x})=1$ and therefore $x^{-1}=x^{n-1}+a_{n-1}x^{n-2}+...+a_1+\frac{a_0+1}{x}$. From this it follows that every subring is a field. Am I right?

For $a \Leftarrow b$

Since every subring $R$ is a field, for every $x \in R$ we have that $x^{-1} \in R$. Therefore $x^{-1}=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}...+a_0$. We have that $x(a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}...+a_0)=1$ and $a_nx^{n+1}+a_{n-1}x^{n}...+(a_0-1)x=0$ so we have fund for every $x \in R$ a polynomial $\in K[X]$ where $x$ is a root. So we have that $L/K$ is algebraic.

I am not sure about my results. Can someone check them?

Comment: Your proof of $a\implies b$ is circular. It produces $x^{-1}$ using $\frac{a_0+1}x$, which presupposes that you can divide by $x$.  In your proof of $b\implies a$, how do you get from $x^{1}\in R$ to $x^{-1}=\dots$, where $\dots$ is a polynomial in $x$? Also at the end of the proof, you use that the coefficients of that polynomial are in $K$ without saying that when introducing that polynomial.

Comment: In your first part you can assume that $x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n=0$ with $a_i\in K, a_n\neq 0$. This implies $1/x=-(x^{n-1}+a_1x^{n-2}+\dots+a_{n-1})/a_n$.